# How to execute a function from a statically loaded library in linux?

Tags: c++, c, static-linking

I am writing a native launcher in linux for a java program. The launcher should load libjvm.so statically and execute the function `JNI_CreateJavaVM()` via a function pointer, so I can launch the executable without having to first set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

I have this so far and I've figured it how to compile and link it, but I'm struggling with the syntax for declaring the function pointer and then later executing the function:

```
JavaVM *jvm;
JNIEnv *env;
JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[10];

...

std::string location = "./jre/lib/server/libjvm.so";
void *handle = dlopen ( location.c_str(), RTLD_LAZY );

if ( !handle ) {
   printf ( "Unable to load %s, exiting", location.c_str() );
   return 0;
}

?? = dlsym ( handle, "JNI_CreateJavaVM" ); //get the function pointer

//This is how I would execute the function if dynamically linking: 
//JNI_CreateJavaVM( &jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args );

?? ( &jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args ); //Execute the function pointer.
```

What magic words do I put in place of the `??`s to make this work? I've tried working through the [dlsym documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlsym), but I'm too unfamiliar with C/C++ to translate it to my situation.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you see the example in the `dlopen` man page? http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html Also, doesn't `JNI` cover this? Also this is **dynamic** loading/linking not "static".

Comment: JNI covers this, but the examples provided by Oracle don't offer examples in this shape -- they require jvm.dll / libjvm.so be in path before executing. I'm not a C/C++ guy at all, so I don't have the lingo down or familiarity with the syntax, but I know this is the basic shape of the solution I need. I have it working in windows, but I can't quite get the syntax right on Linux.

Comment: Why do you wan't to `dlopen` libjvm.so and not link to it normaly? `dlopen` is typicaly used for plugins. If the problem is that ibjvm.so is not in your default library path, you can fix this by setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, declare a type (here `p_JNI_CreateJavaVM`) for the function you want to retrieve:

```
typedef jint (*p_JNI_CreateJavaVM)(JavaVM**, void**, void**);
p_JNI_CreateJavaVM JNI_CreateJavaVM = (p_JNI_CreateJavaVM)dlsym(handle, "JNI_CreateJavaVM");
```

And you can invoke it as usual:

```
jint ret = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
```

Comment: I had to change the typedef to get it to compile: `typedef jint (*p_JNI_CreateJavaVM)(JavaVM**, void**, JavaVMInitArgs* );` Otherwise this worked. Thank you!

Comment: I was going off of [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html) that listed it as `void**`

Comment: I don't know enough C/C++ to make sense of it. The compiler told me `launch.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:  launch.cpp:51:60: error: cannot convert ‘JavaVMInitArgs*’ to ‘void**’ in argument passing jint ret = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);` so I tried changing the last argument to that `JavaVMInitArgs*` and it worked.

Comment: @JoshuaD The JNI spec is technically written for C, and C allows conversion to/from `void *` without a cast.  C++ requires an explicit cast.

Comment: Just because I was curious, if you have access to C++14 you can do `typedef decltype(&JNI_CreateJavaVM) p_JNI_CreateJavaVM;` to get the type without typing (or thinking) so much.